# Using a dll in C++ code

Tags: c++, dll

I want to use pjsipDll.dll in a c++ code. I got this dll from one of the sites, I only know how to build the code to obtain the dll file. So I did that and now I've the pjsipDll.dll file with me. I want to use certain functions in the DLL in my code(C++)

I tried the following code. << I haven't made/added any dll or .h file to the project, there is only the following CPP file>>

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int CallMyDLL(void)
{
    /* get handle to dll */
   HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("G:\\July\\9.0\\pjsipdll\\Lib\\pjsipDll.dll");

   /* get pointer to the function in the dll*/
   FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL),"dll_makeCall");

   /*
      Define the Function in the DLL for reuse. This is just prototyping the dll's function.
      A mock of it. Use "stdcall" for maximum compatibility.
   */
   typedef int (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(int, char *);

   pICFUNC MyFunction;
   MyFunction = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);

   /* The actual call to the function contained in the dll */
   int intMyReturnVal = MyFunction(5,"hello");

   /* Release the Dll */
   FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);

   /* The return val from the dll */
returnintMyReturnVal;
} 
void main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    CallMyDLL();
    getchar();
}
```

I learnt this way from some site, to use the function from a DLL.

The problem is, I get an ERROR:

> error C2065: 'HINSTANCE' : undeclared identifier   g:\july\9.0\pjproject-0.9.0\myproject\importerprojet\importerprojet\mycpp.cpp   9   importerProjet

Can anyone help me out with this. Or atleast point me to the post if this query is already addressed.

Thanks for your help,
Vinu.

Comment: I think you should include `<Windows.h>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `#include <windows.h>`